# Adding a status to PHP Slim 3 response

Tags: php, json, routes, slim, middleware

I have a piece of middleware in Slim 3 that validates a session for each route.  If validation fails, it returns a JSON object with `{ 'status' : false, 'error': 'failed validation' }`.  If validation passes, it adds `'status' : true` to the response JSON object.

How do I insert an object property into the $response?

```
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $valid = doExternalValidation();
    if ($valid == false) {
        return $response->withJSON(
            [ 'status' => false, 'errors' => 'failed validation' ]
        );
    }
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->jsonBody['status'] = true;  // THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO
    return $response;
});

$app->get('/test', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $data = [ "foo" => "bar" ];
    return $response->withJSON([ 'data' => $data ]);
});
```

How can I alter the middleware function so that I get `{ "status" : true, "data" : { "foo" : "bar" } }`?

Comment: You could do something like this in your Middleware `$request = $request->withAttribute("status",true); $response = $next($request, $response); return $response;` and then in your route callback `$status = $request->getAttribute("status");
    return $response->withJSON([ 'status'=>$status,'data' => $data ]);` or you could just return status true by default if it has passed the Middleware

Comment: @DusanJovanov: What's the call to make the status return true by default in the middleware?

Comment: No, I meant in your route callback function to just return status true by default like this `$app->get('/test', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $data = [ "foo" => "bar" ];
    return $response->withJSON(['status'=>true,'data' => $data ]);
});`

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread.  I was looking for a way to just inject the attribute from the middleware....seems like there should be a way to do that, that's the purpose of the middleware.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

1) Rewind the Body, as on the back-side of the middleware the cursor of the body is at the end of the stream

2) Decode the Body (rewind resets the cursor to the head of the message)

3) Mutate the Entity

4) Re-insert the Entity with `withJson`

5) Return the new Json Response

**Sample code:**

```
$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $valid = doExternalValidation();
    if ($valid == false) {
        return $response->withJSON(
            [ 'status' => false, 'errors' => 'failed validation' ]
        );
    }
    $response = $next($request, $response);

    $response->getBody()->rewind();
    $object = json_decode($response->getBody());
    $object['status'] = true;
    return $response->withJson($object);
});
```